# GitHub Actions: Use local action after checkout into different folder

Tags: path, yaml, github-actions, local, checkout

I want my workflow to use a local action.
Normally, one would do that like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  my_first_job:
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use local my-action
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
```

However, I want to checkout my repository in a different path:

```yaml
- name: Check out repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  path: ${{ env.WORK_DIR }}/local_checkout
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '<mypath>/.github/actions/my-action'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

I should note that `my-action` is not in a release or the main branch yet, only my current branch in which I am testing my pipeline.
Unfortunately, something like `uses: ./${{ env.WORK_DIR }}/local_checkout/.github/actions/my-action` does not work, because `env` is unavailable in the context of `uses`.

So my question is: How do I use a local action if I checkout my repository in a different path than the default one?

```yaml
jobs:
  my_first_job:
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        path: ${{ env.WORK_DIR }}/local_checkout
      - name: Use local my-action
        uses: ./${{ env.WORK_DIR }}/local_checkout/.github/actions/my-action
```

Comment: Did you try just copy your action into `.github/actions/my-action` after checking out to custom path?

Comment: Please don't put answer in the comments, it makes them hard to find. And it also means I cannot upvote it - the "copy" trick just helped me.

Comment: I didn't get that `uses: ./.github/actions/my-action` means that you need to have an `action.yml` inside that folder, like this: `.github/actions/my-action/action.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra step after "checkout" to copy the `.github` folder to right location:

```
     - name: Copy files
       working-directory: ${{ env.WORK_DIR }}/local_checkout
       run: cp -r .github "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/"
```

(if you have self-hosted runners which do not clear up their workspace, you might need to change this `cp` to rsync in delete mode to make sure no leftovers are there)